# Python: Error 54 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, solidity, chainlink

I'm getting the folllowing error: ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer') while downloading this: Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/macosx-amd64/solc-macosx-amd64-v0.8.11+commit.d7f03943. Please let me know how I can solve this. Thank you in advance!!!

here is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/ERC677Token.sol";
import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/StandardToken.sol";

contract LinkToken is linkStandardToken, ERC677Token {
    uint256 public constant totalSupply = 10**27;
    string public constant name = "ChainLink Token";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    string public constant symbol = "LINK";

    function LinkToken() public {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev transfer token to a specified address with additional data if the recipient is a contract.
     * @param _to The address to transfer to.
     * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
     * @param _data The extra data to be passed to the receiving contract.
     */
    function transferAndCall(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes _data
    ) public validRecipient(_to) returns (bool success) {
        return super.transferAndCall(_to, _value, _data);
    }

    /**
     * @dev transfer token to a specified address.
     * @param _to The address to transfer to.
     * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        public
        validRecipient(_to)
        returns (bool success)
    {
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
     * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
     * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        public
        validRecipient(_spender)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
     * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
     * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
     * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
     */
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public validRecipient(_to) returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    // MODIFIERS

    modifier validRecipient(address _recipient) {
        require(_recipient != address(0) && _recipient != address(this));
        _;
    }
}
```

Here is an error message:

```
Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/macosx-amd64/solc-macosx-amd64-v0.8.11+commit.d7f03943
 37%|████████████████████████████████████████████▉                                                                             | 14.2M/38.5M [00:53<01:32, 264kiB/s]
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 40, in main
    active_project = project.load()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 751, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 238, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 95, in _compile
    build_json = compiler.compile_and_format(
  File "brownie/project/compiler/__init__.py", line 105, in compile_and_format
    find_solc_versions(solc_sources, install_needed=True, silent=silent)
  File "brownie/project/compiler/solidity.py", line 173, in find_solc_versions
    install_solc(*to_install)
  File "brownie/project/compiler/solidity.py", line 105, in install_solc
    solcx.install_solc(version, show_progress=True)
  File "solcx/install.py", line 454, in install_solc
    _install_solc_unix(version, filename, show_progress, solcx_binary_path)
  File "solcx/install.py", line 603, in _install_solc_unix
    content = _download_solc(download, show_progress)
  File "solcx/install.py", line 589, in _download_solc
    for data in response.iter_content(1024, decode_unicode=True):
  File "requests/utils.py", line 536, in stream_decode_response_unicode
    for item in iterator:
  File "requests/models.py", line 761, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: Curiosity: what is the context of your code? 
Why are you using such an old version of solidity?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the solidity compiler download, you could look for another link to download it.
[solc-bin.ethereum.org](https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/) is deprecated.

Here are updated link:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#static-binaries

One comment: it is trying to download solidity 0.8.11.
Even though the code is for version ^0.4.11, it will not work with this compiler version.

You can check the breaking changes

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Looks like 0.8.11 is already installed and up to date "brew install solidity
Warning: solidity 0.8.11 is already installed and up-to-date." but it still trying to download from deprecated link and ended up in the error. Also, can you pls help me figure out your last commment? Very newie and no clue how to solve the last point.

Comment: A contract created in the solidity version 0.4.11 will not compile using the solidity version 0.8.11.
You will get some compilation errors.
The link above, related to the breaking changes, lists some of the incompatibilities.
You can check from 0.4.x to 0.5.x and the following, until version 0.8.x

Comment: I installed solidity,solidity@7&6, via brew, but still "brownie compile" results in a downloading solc via a deprecated link (solc-bin).  At this point, I just baked chainlnk-mix and just ran brownie compile and getting the same error. Thus, it's not coding error, but setting or some sort. Any help is appreciated!